# ios device onscroll top position fixed

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, mobile-safari

```
function changeHeaderPosition() {   
  $('.header-menu').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 44 + "px");
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeHeaderPosition();
});
```

This code place header-menu div to bottom. How to place on top of page when scroll in ipad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess this would help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150959/how-does-one-get-a-fixed-header-to-stay-at-the-top-of-the-page